# print messages conditionally on resource synchronization

Tags: puppet

is there a way how to print out a message based on a resource synchronization? Something like:
required content of the file is following and if that is updated(synchronized) print a message e.g. Please restart the system.

I tried following

```
  file { 'disableselinux':
ensure => present,
path   => '/etc/selinux/config',
mode   => 0644,
source => "puppet:///modules/base/selinux",
  }

  notify{'SElinuxChange':
    loglevel => warning,
    message => 'System needs restart',
    subscribe => File['disableselinux'],    
  }
```

But that message will be printed every time I guess. Is there any elegant way of doing so avoiding if-then-else flags etc.

Comment: I would not try to solve this in Puppet. Having such user feedback as part of the Puppet log is poor user experience at best. How about triggering an `exec` that sends an e-mail to the admins in charge of the system in question?

Comment: @Fekux - I have another question on SO how to ensre reboot after puppet run. This one I take as a short time solution. Because we use puppet mainly in standalone mode so the user see the message immediately. But in general I fully agree with your point.